# terraform single vars file for all directories

Tags: terraform, hcl

I just started learning terraform. I want to arrange my resources in separate directories like modules e.g.

```
.
├── alb/
├── networking/
├── variables.tf
└── servers/
```

When I run the `terraform validate` command from within any of the directory, there is error saying that the variable(s) not declared.

I don't want to keep variables in every directory.

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help.

Comment: You would need a `main.tf` in the same directory as `variables.tf` and then use other directories as modules: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/composition.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't run `terraform validate` in each of those directories (unless you're doing this from your workstation only). You run it at the top level directory, which has passed the appropriate variables to the `module` blocks.

Generally speaking (and best practice) is to publish your modules to their own repos (or some other module hosting, e.g.: tf enterprise) and set up a pipeline to run `terraform validate` as a step/stage/job/whatever. Once it has completed a successful pipeline run, then you can merge and tag it.

Then you can rest assured that your calling terraform can call those modules, (hopefully by specific versions) knowing there aren't any errors.

If you're just learning terraform, then the chances you're doing this on your local workstation seems high - if I were you, I'd do something like `validate.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in $(ls -d */); do
    pushd $dir
    echo -e "\n\n$dir\n\n"
    terraform validate
    popd
done

echo "*****"
pwd
echo -e "\n"
terraform validate
```

Comment: Oh, I should mention, it's also best practice to place your local modules under a common subdirectory - something like `./modules/`.

Comment: thanks. so its just like CF where each template has its own params, and each folder(module) needs to have its own set of variables.